# What is difference between MQTTAsync_onSuccess and MQTTAsync_deliveryComplete callbacks?

Tags: c, mqtt, paho

I'm learning about MQTT (specifically the paho C library) by reading and experimenting with variations on the async [pub](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTAsync/html/publish.html)/[sub](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTAsync/html/subscribe.html) examples.

What's the difference between the   [MQTTAsync_deliveryComplete](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTAsync/html/_m_q_t_t_async_8h.html#ab10296618e266b3c02fd117d6616b15d) callback that you set with [MQTTAsync_setCallbacks()](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTAsync/html/_m_q_t_t_async_8h.html#ae9ae8d61023e7029ef5a19f5219c3599) vs. the [MQTTAsync_onSuccess](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTAsync/html/_m_q_t_t_async_8h.html#a7b0c18a0e29e2ce73f3ea109bc32617b) or [MQTTAsync_onSuccess5](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTAsync/html/_m_q_t_t_async_8h.html#a892cf122e6e8d8f6cd38c4c8efe8fb67) callbacks that you set in the [MQTTAsync_responseOptions](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTAsync/html/struct_m_q_t_t_async__response_options.html) struct that you pass to [MQTTAsync_sendMessage()](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTAsync/html/_m_q_t_t_async_8h.html#a5687171e67e98f9ea590c9e3b64cde18) ?

All seem to deal with "successful delivery" of published messages, but from reading the example code and doxygen, I can't tell how they relate to or conflict with or supplement each other. Grateful for any guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically MQTTAsync_deliveryComplete and MQTTAsync_onSuccess do the same, they notify you via callback about the delivery of a message. Both callbacks are executed asynchronously on a separate thread to the thread on which the client application is running.

(Both callbacks are even using the same thread in the case of the current version of the Paho client, but this is a non-documented implementation detail. This thread used by MQTTAsync_deliveryComplete and MQTTAsync_onSuccess is of course not the application thread otherwise it would not be an asynchronous callback).

The difference is that MQTTAsync_deliveryComplete callback is set *once* via MQTTAsync_setCallbacks and then you are informed about *every* delivery of a message.

In contrast to this, the MQTTAsync_onSuccess informs you *once* for exactly the message that you send out via MQTTAsync_sendMessage().

You can even define both callbacks, which will *both* be called when a message is delivered.

This gives you the flexibility to choose the approach that best suits your needs.

**Artificial example**

Suppose you have three different functions, each sending a specific type of message (e.g. sendTemperature(), sendHumidity(), sendAirPressure()) and in each function you call MQTTAsync_sendMessage, and after each delivery you want to call a matching callback function, then you would choose MQTTAsync_onSuccess. Then you do not need to keep track of MQTTAsync_token and associate that with your callbacks.

For example, if you want to implement a logging function instead, it would be more useful to use MQTTAsync_deliveryComplete because it is called for *every* delivery.

And of course one can imagine that one would want to have both the specific one with some actions and the generic one for logging, so in this case both variants could be used at the same time.

**Documentation**

You should note that MQTTAsync_deliveryComplete explicitly states in its documentation that it takes into account the Quality of Service Set. This is not the case in the MQTTAsync_onSuccess documentation, but of course it does not mean that this is not done in the implementation. But if this is important, you should explicitly check the source code.